# How do I change the lock Pattern !!!! - Lenovo A7000

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens

i have lenovo A7000, and i had recently had performed a reset, but, after setting the pattern, now i want to change the pattern as my brothers know the pattern. so, whenever i go to security settings and try to change it, the screen becomes repetitive and asks me to confirm the pattern infinite times, after giving the correct pattern too it again asks the same.... i cannot the change the lock as there is no screen to set it on the different modes like pin etc. what should i do ??? i tried clearing the certificates but it is grey and i dont want to hard reset or format the phone now.... pls tell me the correct way to go through it......